# How to read .txt thousands of files from S3 bucket in python pandas faster

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, etl

Please help me to get to a solution to read multiple files from the S3 bucket in python pandas in an efficient way. I am doing an ETL which reads the log files from the S3 bucket, transform it accordingly and load it into Redshift. In an hour the log files can be generated in thousands starting 1600 files minimum and can go up to 2500 files. Each file size is about 5MB. I am using the below piece of code to read the files from the S3 bucket to append in Pandas data frame (one hour of data):

```
self.query_date1_d = '2020-09-01 10:00:00'
self.query_date2_d = '2020-09-01 11:00:00'
self.filter_date1 = '2020-09-01'

 '''Creating a PageIterator from the Paginator to load objects from S3 bucket'''
        self.page_iterator = self.paginator.paginate(**self.operation_parameters)

        self.jsondf = pd.DataFrame()
        self.s3_files = []
        for self.page in self.page_iterator:
            for self.s3_objects in self.page['Contents']:
                if self.filter_date1 in self.s3_objects['Key']:
                    self.file_name = self.s3_objects['Key']
                    self.last_modified_date = self.s3_objects['LastModified']
                    self.object_date = self.last_modified_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    self.object_date = datetime.strptime(self.object_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    if self.query_date1_d <= self.object_date < self.query_date2_d:
                        self.s3_files.append(self.file_name)
                        print(self.file_name + ' :: ' + str(self.object_date))
                        self.obj = self.client.get_object(Bucket=self.my_bucket, Key=self.file_name)
                        self.initial_df = pd.read_json(self.obj['Body'], lines=True)
                        self.jsondf = self.jsondf.append(self.initial_df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
        return self.jsondf
```

But this is taking more than 2 hours just to read the files from S3 and append it in the Pandas data frame. Is there any efficient way to read the files quickly? Currently, the bucket contains around 20000 files already.
Please help me with this!

Below is the JSON example:

```
{
    "env": "production",
    "event_type": "RESPONSE",
    "log_type": "rest-api",
    "method": "GET",
    "user_id": "wcel",
    "mid": "wcel",
    "request_uri": "",
    "app_name": "DF",
    "ecs": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "@timestamp": "2020-08-27T06:27:11.293Z",
    "tags": ["Some", "DF", "out-S3", "out-elastic-search"],
    "ip_address": "00.00.00.00",
    "log_time": "2020-08-27 06:27:11",
    "payload": {
        "Excel2Offer": [{
            "contractType": "SIB",
            "prodName": "Olivier",
            "price": 1800.0,
            "qty": 1,
            "marketPrice": null,
            "marketPriceDate": null,
            "contractId": 807225,
            "unitSize": "2",
            "lastTradeDate": null,
            "code": "2154",
            "lastChangeOn": 548798,
            "lastListPrice": null,
            "wUrl": "/n11=10197192014",
            "yourId": null,
            "specialInfo": null,
            "orderGuid": "2f75132e-6ff0-498c-978d-f57bc5953ec1",
            "xCode": null,
            "lastListDate": null,
            "lastTradePrice": null,
            "year": "2014",
            "region": "south"
        }],
        "Excel2Offer1": [{
            "contractType": "SIB",
            "prodName": "Olivier",
            "price": 1800.0,
            "qty": 1,
            "marketPrice": null,
            "marketPriceDate": null,
            "contractId": 807225,
            "unitSize": "2",
            "lastTradeDate": null,
            "code": "2154",
            "lastChangeOn": 548798,
            "lastListPrice": null,
            "wUrl": "/n11=10197192014",
            "yourId": null,
            "specialInfo": null,
            "orderGuid": "2f75132e-6ff0-498c-978d-f57bc5953ec1",
            "xCode": null,
            "lastListDate": null,
            "lastTradePrice": null,
            "year": "2014",
            "region": "south"
        }]
    },
    "relation_id": "5487we-asd4-87we-65qw-54a2154qw"
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do the files contain? Why use Pandas in the first place, what transformation are you performing that can't be performed by Redshift using SQL? Redshift was built to make ingesting 1TB of data as quickly as 1MB. Which means that reading 2000 small files takes 2000 times longer than reading 1 large file

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. The files contain the json response and each response contains multiple json data that needs to be transformed into a tabular structure for the data insights team for business intelligence reports.

Comment: [Redshift can import JSON files directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html). It can also [import multiple files in parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-single-copy-command.html). You can load [all files with a specific prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html) with a single COPY command. If you don't want that, you can specify the files to import in a manifest file

Comment: Ok, thank you for the alternate solution, much appreciated.
But, I am looking for a solution to read files faster in python from the S3 bucket. If I go for alternate I will have to change my other dependencies.

Comment: AWS Glue uses Spark to run multiple jobs in parallel. It might be suitable for needs.

Comment: @Aakash this isn't the alternative, it's the *default*. What you try to do is an alternative, but you haven't explained *why* - what dependencies? What does it matter if your Python code executes a parallel `COPY` in a single line or a client-side parsing and ... `COPY` in a lot of lines, if the outcome is the same? You can try performing multiple imports in parallel in Python, but that still requires pulling the data to the client and sending it back to Redshift. `COPY` alone will pull the data directly from S3

Comment: Ok, so my actual challenge here is, how can I modify the data?
Going with your solution, If I directly ingest the JSON files in Redshift, the end result will have another column that has multiple responses for each response recorded.

So when a user hits the website, it records its activity including the input data for different fields. One main response can have 200-300 json responses in a payload section.
In that case how redshift will increase the records from 1 response to 300 rows?
That is why I am doing some transformation of data including cleaning with string functions on pandas

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have added a JSON example for your reference. One row can have multiple JSON responses.

Comment: @Aakash - use python https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html. You need a machine with multiple cores (you can have a machine like this using EC2). Your code will run in parallel

Comment: [There's an SO answer for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100988/how-can-i-import-nested-json-data-into-multiple-connected-redshift-subtables) You can use JSONPath expressions to specify how to extract data. Once you load the data into Redshift you can use SQL for further transformations.

Comment: Even if you don't use COPY, you have to address the causes for the delays. Those are the network latencies which are *far greater* than your local network and Redshift's own ingress latencies. If you process files one by one you pay the full cost of those latencies - in fact, you pay the network latencies twice, S3->client and client->Redshift.

Comment: If you perform *multiple* operations in parallel, the latencies don't add up (although COPY will still do parallel insertion faster than the client code). You still pay for the double trip, still pay for the processing cost, but at least it will be far less than 2000x the cost of a single transform. *Maybe* if you convert the source files and store the *converted* results to new JSON files, you can use COPY to ingest them, paying only for the client-side transformation.

Comment: With all cloud services, efficiency means *cost* efficiency too. Parallel client-side transformations mean you need a beefy VM, which can end up costing more than using AWS Glue. So you may have to consider that too, if you have transformations so complex you can't perform them in SQL. Redshift is fast enough you can perform transformations on the fly, by paying for a bigger cluster. You have to do the math to see which solution is more efficient.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein should we page Correy Quinn on this? :P